# Directional derivative, finding the direction in which the slope is the largest

Tags: calculus

> Suppose you are climbing a hill whose slope is given by $$z = 400 - .05 x^2 - .01 y^2$$
>   where $x,y,z$ is measured in terms of meters. Now you are standing at $(20,20,376)$. The positive $x$-axis points east and the positive $y$-axis points north.
>   a.) If you walk due southeast, will you start to ascend or descend? At what rate?
>   b.) In which direction is the slope the largest? What is the rate of ascend in that direction?

Attempted solution a.) - We need to calculate the directional derivative $D_{u}f(x,y)\cdot\textbf{u}$. We have $$D_u f(20,20)\cdot\textbf{u} = <-1.4142,-.2828>$$
Thus we must be descending. The rate is given by 
$$\left|\nabla f(x,y)\right| = 2.0396$$

I left some of the details out but I am not sure if this is right or how to proceed with b.). This is a problem I am doing for my client I tutor in calc 3

Comment: What is $u$...?

Comment: You have $D_u$ equal to a vector?

Comment: $u$ is the unit vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\nabla f(20,20) = (-2, -.4)$$

$a)$  The directional derivative going south-east, that is going in the direction of the vector $(1,-1)$, is $$<\nabla f(20,20),(1,-1)>=-1.6.$$ So you'll start to descend at a rate of $1.6$.

$b)$  The direction in which the slope is the largest is the direction of the gradient. So, the direction of the vector $(-2, -.4)$. We have $$<(-2, -.4),(-2, -.4)>=4.16,$$ so if you take this direction you'll start to ascend, at a rate of $4.16$.

Comment: You’ve got the square of the length of the gradient instead of its length.

Answer (score 1):

a) You have $\nabla z=(-0.1x,-0.02y)=(-2,-0.4)$.

Directional derivative in the direction $u=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ (Note that this is a unit vector):

$$\nabla z\cdot u = \frac{-4\sqrt{2}}{5}\approx -1.13 \implies \text{descending}.$$

b) The slope is steepest in the direction of the gradient, which you have computed correctly:

$$|\nabla z(20,20)|=\sqrt{(-2)^2+(-0.4)^2}\approx2.03.$$